# Select to return NULL on left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the following data:

**Users**

```
user    | online
-------- -------
1       | 1
2       | 0
3       | 1
4       | 1
5       | 0
```

**Photos**

```
user_id | photo
-------- -------
1       | photo1.jpg
1       | photo2.jpg
2       | photo3.jpg
3       | photo4.jpg
```

I want to select all users that are online (online = 1) whether the user has a photo or not, showing the count or null, or zero, if the user has no photos. Using the tables above, it would be something like this:

```
user_id | count
-------- ------
1       | 2
3       | 1
4       | null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    u.user user_id,
    case when count(p.user_id) > 0 then count(p.user_id) end `count`
from users u
left join photos p on u.user = p.user_id
where u.online = 1
group by u.user;
```

You can Left join the photos to users and group it over the user to find count. If count is more than 0 then get the count or else null.